# winforms add newline (environmental.Newline) to textbox in code not working

Tags: c#, winforms

Here is my code to loop through an array to string and trying to set the text to the textbox

```
foreach (var row in result.discount_section)
{
     string name = row.name;
     string value = row.amount;
     s += name + " : " + value;
     s += Environment.NewLine;
}
order_discount_section.Text = s;
```

`s += Environment.NewLine` is not working and it still display the text in one line, anyone know what is the problem?

[image]

Comment: A TextBox only displays a single line by default.

Comment: The picture that you share, shows textbox has single line, What I mean is your loop runs only 1 time, because there is only 1 `":"`.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the multiline property of your TextBox to true (the default value is false).

```
order_discount_section.Multiline = true;
```

(It can also be set in the Designer)

Comment: Like mentioned above, the loop is only called one time.

Answer (score 0):

First use `StringBuilder` because of performance problems and then use `RichTextBox` then write the result please.